# Серверная обработка изменений Store ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, php

Здравствуйте!
Разбираюсь с ExtJS, с переменным успехом... 
Ни как не могу принять на сервере данные отправляемые **Store** при изменении записей (добавлении, изменении или удалении). Пишет что данные уходят *POST*-ом, но на сервере ни ***$_POST***, ни ***$_GET***, ни ***$_REQUEST*** отправленные данные не показывает - как будто ничего не отправлялось (ну кроме случайного значение в ***$_GET*** - **_dc=1357565039902**).

Вот что уходит на сервер (взял из консоли Хрома), соответственно, при удалении, обновлении и добавлении:

```
Request URL:http://localhost/service/destroy/news.php?_dc=1357565811429
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Query String Parameters:
  _dc:1357565811429
Request Payload:
  {"items":{"id":5}}

Request URL:http://localhost/service/update/news.php?_dc=1357566047052
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Query String Parameters:
  _dc:1357566047052
Request Payload:
  {"items":{"datepubl":"2012-12-01T00:00:00","title":"the Update Plan","alias":"the-update-plan","new":"<p>small text new</p>","newfull":"<p>full text new</p>","id":4}}

Request URL:http://localhost/service/create/news.php?_dc=1357566179903
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Query String Parameters:
  _dc:1357566179903
Request Payload:
  {"items":{"id":0,"datepubl":null,"dateclose":null,"title":"the NEW new","alias":"the-new-new","new":"text the NEW new","newfull":""}}
```

Посылает эти запросы следующий **Store**:

```
var storeNews = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    idProperty: 'id',
    remoteFilter: true,
    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'datepubl', type: 'date' },
        { name: 'dateclose', type: 'date' },
        { name: 'title', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'alias', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'new', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'newtext', type: 'string' }
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: 'service/view/news.php',
            create: 'service/create/news.php',
            update: 'service/update/news.php',
            destroy: 'service/destroy/news.php'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            successProperty: 'success',
            root: 'data',
            messageProperty: 'message'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields: false,
            root: 'data'
        },
        listeners: {
            exception: function(proxy, response, operation){
                Ext.MessageBox.show({
                    title: 'REMOTE EXCEPTION',
                    msg: operation.getError(),
                    icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как принять переданные данные на сервера ?
Или как их правильно отправить, если я делаю это не верно ?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все проще чем кажется:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

**Store** хочет в ответе получить готовый вид этой записи. Только тогда он будет уверен, что эта строка таблицы существует на самом деле, а не является какой то "вымышленной". У каждой записи в **store** есть свойство ***phantom***. Оно означает, существует ли запись реально, или она временно появилась в store. По добавлению **store** будет отсылать все фантомные записи. Когда **store** получит в ответе данные записи, он поймет, что сервер её обработал или сохранил, и присвоит значение ***phantom = false***, то есть запись реальная.

```
print( json_encode( $data ) );
```

Если выполняется добавление записи, то ей должен быть присвоен ***ID***, если такой имеет место быть.